# Android AlarmManager send notification every time app starts instead of only once

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

My app use an `AlarmManager` that start a `BroadcastReceiver`.
The `BroadcastReceiver` generate a reminder notification to the user.

This is the MainActivity that start the Alarm

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

// Checking whether current hour is over 14
        if (curHr >= 14)
        {
            // Since current hour is over 14, setting the date to the next day
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
// Schedule alarm manager

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
        // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


    }
```

And this is the `BroadcastReceiver` that generate the notification

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");

        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        Log.v("ADebugTag", "It work!");

        int mId = 0;
        //Show the notification here.
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_edit)
                        .setContentTitle("Diario Scolastico")
                        .setContentText("You have homeworks for tomorrow!")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setDefaults(-1);

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());

        //Release the lock
        wl.release();
    }
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

As you can see the alarm must start at 14 PM, but i receive the notification every time that i start the app.
There is something wrong in my code?

I use the [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for setting the alarm every day at same hour, but don't work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are setting the time to current day. So if you are opening your app after 14:00, your alarm manager will immediately fire.

You need to check whether the time is over 14:00 for the current day, if yes you need to change the date to the next day:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

// Checking whether current hour is over 14
if (curHr >= 14)
{
   // Since current hour is over 14, setting the date to the next day
   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
// Schedule alarm manager
```

Comment: Or i can remove the alarm?
For example at 14:00 the alarm fire, if it's not fire and i open the app it fire too (and it's ok).
But if i see the notification and i click it for open the app why it return again the notification fired?
I need to delete it after firing?
I try with `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` but it continue to generate notification.

Comment: @Dario: That's the reason I mentioned above. You are creating the alarm in your main activity's onCreate method. Each time you open the app the scheduling will happen (Since you are scheduling it in the same way before, it will over-write the previous one). And due to the scheduling time already passed,it will fire again.

Comment: Ok now i change the hour with 20PM (actual) so i can see how it work with your code!
If it work i check your answere!

Comment: I edit the post with your code, but now nothig happens.
No nofication, never!
I don't know why...